# how to import maven-based projects into Eclipse effectively for large projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to import `maven`-based projects in `Eclipse`. For example, here is a project that I am interested in importing to my `Eclipse` workspace.

I have two options:

1. since the project directory has a `pom.xml` in it, I can do

`import > Existing Maven Projects`

The project gets loaded into workspace.

2. run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in the directory containing `pom.xml`. with this, an `eclipse` project is created (i.e `.classpath` and `.project` files).

I can then do

`import > Existing Projects into Workspace`

But with the second option, when I do

`right-click on the project > run As > ....`,

I do not see any options to run `maven commands` (such as `Maven build`, `Maven build...`).

however, with the option 1, I can see these run configurations.

**Q1)** what is the recommended way to import existing maven projects into Eclispse. 1 or 2 or something else?

**Q2)** why in option 2, `maven commands` are not available and how to get them back upon right click on the project.

Thanks.

Just clarify, what I mean, here is the screen-shot:

[image]

Comment: it could be you have to convert the imported project to a maven project when you import it as an existing project instead of as a maven project; for that, right-click on the Project and select Configure>Convert to Maven Project; i'm not sure if this will use an existing pom.xml file or create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me I always use the m2e (First option) to import maven projects to Eclipse workspace.
And for the second option Right click on the project go to configure then "convert to Maven project", the project will be treated as a Maven project.

Answer (score 1):

Q1) what is the recommended way to import existing maven projects into Eclispse. 1 or 2 or something else?

I don't use the command line, it give me problems too. Do like this: file menu, import, choose Maven and select existing maven project, then just select you project location.

Q2) why in option 2, maven commands are not available and how to get them back upon right click on the project.

If Eclipse does not give to you the possibility to run maven command means that Eclipse does not recognize you project as a Maven project. So right click on the project, click configuration and convert the project to maven project.